# How can I show sum of a foreign key values in object_list

Tags: python, django

I have an product list and a separated quantity table for these products. I want to show product quantities but I couldn't manage it yet.

There is more than one quantity card for each product and, I want to show sum of them.

Here is my related models: stok=quantity, Urunler=Products (sorry for language)

```
class Urunler(models.Model):

    urun_adi = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    urun_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    barkod = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    gtin = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    varkod = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    urun_kodu = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True,unique=True)
    raf_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True,null=True)
    kdv = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    birim_fiyat = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    fiyatlansin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ürün"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ürünler"
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.urun_adi

biryil =  datetime.now()+timedelta(days=365)


class StokKart(models.Model):

    urun = models.ForeignKey(Urunler,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stoklar")
    expiration = models.DateTimeField(default=biryil)
    stok = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=9, decimal_places=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Stok Kartı"
        verbose_name_plural = "Stok Kartları"
        ordering = ['expiration']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.urun
```

my views:

```
class UrunList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Urunler
    paginate_by = 40
    ordering = ['-pk']
    template_name = "urunler.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        urun_list = Urunler.objects.all()

        urun_filter = UrunFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=urun_list)
        context['filter'] = urun_filter
        return context
```

and my template:

```
 {% for object in object_list %}
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        {{object.urun_kodu}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="{% url 'urun-detay' object.pk %}" title="{{ object.urun_adi }}" style="color:black;">{{object.urun_adi}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.barkod}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.urun_id}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {% for stok in object.stoklar.all %}
                           {{stok.stok}}
                       {% endfor %} 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.raf_yeri}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {% if object.fiyatlansin == True %}<a href="{% url 'fiyatlansin' object.pk %}"><button class="btn btn-success success-icon-notika btn-reco-mg btn-button-mg waves-effect">{{object.birim_fiyat}}</button></a>{%else%}{{object.birim_fiyat}}{%endif%}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                          <a href="{% url 'urun-detay' object.pk %}" title="Düzenle"><btn class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success btn-round btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></btn></a> <a href="{% url 'urunsil' object.pk %}" title="Sil"><btn class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger btn-round btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></btn></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      {%endfor%}
```

Right now my code shows the quantities in array on template page. I want to show sum of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I've added a function to my Urunler model and used it at my template like this:

my model:

```
class Urunler(models.Model):

    urun_adi = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    urun_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    barkod = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    gtin = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    varkod = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    urun_kodu = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True,null=True,unique=True)
    raf_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True,null=True)
    kdv = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
    birim_fiyat = models.DecimalField(blank=True,null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    fiyatlansin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def toplam_stok(self):
        toplam = StokKart.objects.filter(urun=self).aggregate(Sum('stok'))

        return toplam
```

and my template:

```
 {% for object in object_list %}
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                        {{object.urun_kodu}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="{% url 'urun-detay' object.pk %}" title="{{ object.urun_adi }}" style="color:black;">{{object.urun_adi}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.barkod}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.urun_id}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.toplam_stok.stok__sum}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{object.raf_yeri}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {% if object.fiyatlansin == True %}<a href="{% url 'fiyatlansin' object.pk %}"><button class="btn btn-success success-icon-notika btn-reco-mg btn-button-mg waves-effect">{{object.birim_fiyat}}</button></a>{%else%}{{object.birim_fiyat}}{%endif%}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                          <a href="{% url 'urun-detay' object.pk %}" title="Düzenle"><btn class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success btn-round btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></btn></a> <a href="{% url 'urunsil' object.pk %}" title="Sil"><btn class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger btn-round btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></btn></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      {%endfor%}
```